# Failed to create a table on in-memory sqlite database without any error message

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to create a table on in-memory sqlite database. I have a method called `createTable` to create a table which initializes a connection to the database with `getConnection` method.

**createTable:**

```
private void createTable() {
    try {
        final Connection connection = getConnection();
        final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE videos (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(255), description TEXT, path TEXT, category VARCHAR(255), published INTEGER DEFAULT 0, created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);");
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Failed to create table.", e);
    }
}
```

**getConnection**

```
private static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Failed to get connection.", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

To test the database I wrote a simple `insert` method:

```
public void insert() {
    try {
        final Connection connection = getConnection();
        final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(
            "INSERT INTO videos (title, path, category) VALUES ('test title', 'test path', 'test category');");
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Failed to insert.", e);
    }
}
```

When I do

```
this.createTable();
this.insert();
```

I got the following error:

```
2017-09-17 22:38:02 WARN  Database:128 - Failed to insert.
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: videos)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:886)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec(NativeDB.java:87)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeUpdate(JDBC3Statement.java:116)...
```

For connections I am using **org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc**'s v`3.20.0`.

Any ideas why table is not getting created? I am not seeing any exception or anything. [SQLFiddle for the example above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/040ba/1) seems to be fine.

Comment: Does it work if you use the same database connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I read [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) correctly, the database only exists within its database connection by default:

> Instead, a new database is created purely in memory. The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed. Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two independent in-memory databases.

The easiest fix would be to not open a second connection, but keep using the connection that you used to create the table for the other database queries as well.

If you want to open multiple connections, you can set the `?cache=shared` parameter on the database url.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Changing connection string from `jdbc:sqlite:` to `jdbc:sqlite:?cache=shared` solved the problem.